# CredentialProvider does not accept passwords with special (German) letters

Tags: winapi, credential-providers

I wrote a CredentialProvider that allows to log in to Windows. But today I found out this strange error that `GetSerialization()` seems not to accept passwords which contain the German 'umlaut' letters like 'ä' or 'ü'. Does anyone know the solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check if the project is set to use unicode character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll depend on the details of the format in which `GetSerialization()` returns the password.

If your CredentialProvider returns a serialized `KERB_INTERACTIVE_UNLOCK_LOGON` structure, as the standard password provider does, then the username, password, and domain name values in the structure must all be passed as `UNICODE_STRING` values. Note that `UNICODE_STRING` is a structure that contains current length and maximum length values and a buffer of 16-bit Unicode (UTF-16LE) characters. As they're Unicode they can certainly hold letters with umlauts.

However, if your CredntialProvider handles the password in a narrow character buffer you may be handling your umlaut characters as 8-bit Windows CP1252 characters. You'll need to convert those to 16-bit Unicode before placing them in the `KERB_INTERACTIVE_UNLOCK_LOGON` structure and serializing it.

Comment: Thank you. The error was caused by a wrong ANSI to unicode string conversion.